# Can we have multiple activities that extend CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I need to have more than one CursorAdapter such that each would refer to a certain fragment. However I noticed that only one CursorAdapter is working. I need to know what should be done to make both work.

PlatformCursorAdapter accesses table store

```
public class PlatformCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = PlatformCursorAdapter.class.getName();

public PlatformCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //find which fields should be populated
    TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView itemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
    final TextView itemQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
    final TextView itemWeight = view.findViewById(R.id.item_weight);
    TextView supplierName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_supplier_name);
    TextView supplierNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_supplier_number);

    //find the columns of pets we're interested in
    final String mItemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME));
    String mItemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE));
    final String mItemQuantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY));
    final String mItemWeight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_WEIGHT));
    String mSupplierName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME));
    final String mSupplierNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NUMBER));

    //get current item id
    int currentId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(StoreEntry._ID));
    //Create the content Uri for the current Id
    final Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(StoreEntry.CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(currentId));

    //populate fields RecipeFragment
    itemName.setText(mItemName);
    itemPrice.setText(mItemPrice);
    itemQuantity.setText(mItemQuantity);
    itemWeight.setText(mItemWeight);
    supplierName.setText(mSupplierName);
    supplierNumber.setText(mSupplierNumber);
}
}
```

and this is the RecipeCursorAdapter which accesses the recipies table

```
public class RecipeCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = RecipeCursorAdapter.class.getName();

public RecipeCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor1){
    super(context, cursor1, 0);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipe_activity, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //find which fields would be populated
    TextView recipeName = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
    TextView recipeType = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_type);
    TextView recipeServings = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_servings);
    TextView recipeValues = view.findViewById(R.id.ingrediant_name_1);

    //get the data from the table recipes
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Number of Columns " + cursor.getColumnCount());
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "This is the Cursor Location " + cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_SERVINGS));
    String mRecipeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME));
    String mRecipeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_TYPE));
    String mRecipeServings = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_SERVINGS));
    String mRecipeValues = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_VALUES));

    //get current item Id
    int currenId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry._ID));
    //create a content Uri for the current Id
    final Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(RecipeEntry.CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(currenId));

    //populate fields with their respective data
    recipeName.setText(mRecipeName);
    recipeType.setText(mRecipeType);
    recipeServings.setText(mRecipeServings);
    recipeValues.setText(mRecipeValues);

}
}
```

I noticed that the RecipeCursorAdapter is referring to the store table as well, and generating an error.

```
    05-26 17:51:33.218 3468-3468/com.example.android.businessplatform E/com.example.android.businessplatform.RecipeCursorAdapter: Number of Columns 7
    This is the Cursor Location -1
05-26 17:51:33.218 3468-3468/com.example.android.businessplatform E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 7 columns.
05-26 17:51:33.220 3468-3468/com.example.android.businessplatform E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.businessplatform, PID: 3468
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
        at com.example.android.businessplatform.RecipeCursorAdapter.bindView(RecipeCursorAdapter.java:37)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:289)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2413)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1331)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1238)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1489)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:729)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19937)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1747)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6782)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:933)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:742)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:674)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:919)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: post full stacktrace, btw why dont you use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the SimpleCursorAdapter, can you help with that?

Comment: later, first call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow` inside `RecipeCursorAdapter#bindView`, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: same error occured

Comment: what do you see on the logcat? just call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow` as the first statement inside `bindView`

Comment: This is showing additional in the Logcat
05-26 18:07:01.889 4491-4491/com.example.android.businessplatform I/System.out: 0 {
       _id=1
       product_name=Flour
       product_price=4
       product_quantity=3
       product_weight=1
       supplier_name=Panda
       supplier_number=1414
    }


this is the data of the store table

Comment: are those columns the same as `RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_*`?

Comment: ok i see that they are not: you are simply passing wrong `Cursor`: with `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_quantity` etc

Comment: I have set the right cursor in the InventoryFragment (first fragment) 
        mCursorAdapter = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
however I noticed that the error only occurs when I insert the first item to the table "store"

Comment: ok did you see the column names printed by `dumpCurrentRow`? are those columns the same as `RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_*` which you use in `cursor.getColumnIndex`?

Comment: no they aren't, those columns are for the StoreEntry table.

Comment: so you are using wrong `Cursor`in your `RecipeCursorAdapter` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message :-

```
05-26 17:51:33.218 3468-3468/com.example.android.businessplatform E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 7 columns.
```

Is saying that there is no column at offset -1 in the cursor which has 2 rows and 7 columns. So offsets 0-6 would correlate to columns in the cursor.

You are getting **-1** because the `getColumnIndex` method returns **-1** when a specified column is not one of the columns in the Cursor.

e.g. if you had a table with columns col1, col2 and you ran a query that created Cursor c then :-

`c.getColumnIndex("col1")` would return an offfset of 0.
`c.getColumnIndex("col2")` would return an offfset of 1.

whilst   `c.getColumnIndex("col3")` would return an offfset of -1 as there is no column named **col3**.

Exactly why the column name does not exist cannot be determined just from the adapter's as the likely issue is a combination of the cursor passed to the adapter and the columns being accessed within the adapter. So the code used to invoke the adapter's would be required to establish the exact cause.

As such you need to check that the Cursor's being passed to the adpaters contain the expected columns. You could do this by using the `DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow` method in the `bindView` method of the adapter and then checking the output to the log.

---

Here's a very basic example of two fragments each with a list (StoreEntry and RecipeeEntry) but based upon some of your code.

It has a **StoreEntry** class as :-

```
public class StoreEntry {
    public static final String TBNAME = "store_entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "product_quantity";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_WEIGHT = "product_weight";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME = "supplier_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NUMBER = "supplier_number";
}
```

and a **RecipeeEntry** class as :-

```
public class RecipeeEntry {
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPEE_SERVINGS = "recipee_servings";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPEE_NAME = "recipee_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPEE_TYPE = "recipee_type";
    public static final String COLUMN_RECIPEE_VALUES = "recipee_values";
}
```

A Database helper class **DBHelper** :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBSTORE = "store";
    public static final String TBRECIPEE = "recipee";

    private static final String store_crt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TBSTORE + "(" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE + " REAL, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " INTEGER, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_WEIGHT + " INTEGER, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NUMBER + " INTEGER" +
            ")";

    private static final String recipee_crt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TBRECIPEE + "(" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
            RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_SERVINGS + " INTEGER, " +
            RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_VALUES + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(store_crt);
        db.execSQL(recipee_crt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addStore(String product_name,
                         Float product_price,
                         int product_quantity,
                         int product_weight,
                         String supplier_name,
                         int supplier_number) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME,product_name);
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE,product_price);
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_QUANTITY,product_quantity);
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_WEIGHT,product_weight);
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME,supplier_name);
        cv.put(StoreEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NUMBER,supplier_number);
        return mDB.insert(TBSTORE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getStoreEntries() {
        return mDB.query(TBSTORE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public long addRecipee(String recipee_name, String recipee_type,int recipee_servings, String recipee_values) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_NAME, recipee_name);
        cv.put(RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_TYPE,recipee_type);
        cv.put(RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_SERVINGS,recipee_servings);
        cv.put(RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_VALUES,recipee_values);
        return mDB.insert(TBRECIPEE,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getRecipeeEntries() {
        return mDB.query(TBRECIPEE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

A very basic MainActivity, that will add some data if none exists :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements
        StoreEntryFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        RecipeeEntryFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TBSTORE) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.addStore("Rice",1.53f,10,1000,"The Rice Company",1);
            mDBHlpr.addStore("Bran",2.34f,100,500,"BranDed",25);
        }
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TBRECIPEE) < 1) {
            mDBHlpr.addRecipee("RiceCrisps","Yucky",10,"This and that");
            mDBHlpr.addRecipee("Bran Flakes","Makes you go",5,"Flakes or something");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }
}
```

A class StoreEntryFragment :-

```
public class StoreEntryFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    ListView mStoreList;

    public StoreEntryFragment() {
    }

    public static StoreEntryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        StoreEntryFragment fragment = new StoreEntryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_entry, container, false);
        mStoreList = view.findViewById(R.id.store_entry_listview);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getStoreEntries();
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mCsr,
                new String[]{StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME,StoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2}
        );
        mStoreList.setAdapter(mSCA);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

- NOTE the code in the onCreateView method and the variables defined beforehand.
- This uses a SimpleCursorAdapter with a supplied layout.
- processing is

  1. get the ListView according to it's id.
  2. get an instance of the DBHelper.
  3. get the cursor for this list.
  4. create the instance of the SimpleCursorAdapter using the cursor just retrieved.
  5. attach (set) the adapter to the ListView.

Here's the equivalent for the RecipeeList (basically the same) :-

```
public class RecipeeEntryFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    ListView mRecipeeList;


    public RecipeeEntryFragment() {
    }

    public static RecipeeEntryFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RecipeeEntryFragment fragment = new RecipeeEntryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipee_entry, container, false);
        mRecipeeList = view.findViewById(R.id.recipee_entry_listview);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getRecipeeEntries();
        Log.d("RECIPEEFRAG","Number of rows in Cursor is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getCount()));
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mCsr,
                new String[]{RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_NAME,RecipeeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPEE_TYPE},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}
                );
        mRecipeeList.setAdapter(mSCA);
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

result is :-

[image]

layouts are :-

**activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <fragment
            android:name="flv.fragmentlistviews.StoreEntryFragment"
            android:id="@+id/store_entry_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:name="flv.fragmentlistviews.RecipeeEntryFragment"
            android:id="@+id/recipee_entry_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_store_entry.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StoreEntryFragment"
    android:background="#AA00FF55">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/store_entry_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="#FF00EE33">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_recipee_entry.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecipeeEntryFragment"
    android:background="#AA0055FF">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipee_entry_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="#FF0033EE">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Moving On

From the above it's a short step to introduce your adapters (code as per the question), which do work.

- Notes

  - Minor changes were made due to my use of recipee instead of recipe.
  - StoreEntry and RecipeeEntry were also amended to inlcude the `_ID` and `CONTENT_URI` constants.

For the **StoreEntryFragment** :-

1. Add another class variable for the PlatformCursorAdapter :-
       PlatformCursorAdapter mPCA;

   So you'd have :-

   ```
   DBHelper mDBHlpr;
   Cursor mCsr;
   SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
   ListView mStoreList;
   PlatformCursorAdapter mPCA; //<<<< ADDED
   ```
2. In the `onCreateViewMethod` after line `mStoreList.setAdapter(mSCA);` and before `return View` add the following 2 lines :-

   ```
   mPCA = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),mCsr);
   mStoreList.setAdapter(mPCA);
   ```

For the **RecipeeEntryFragment** you'd have :-

```
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    ListView mRecipeeList;
    RecipeCursorAdapter mRCA; //<<<< ADDED
```

and :-

```
    mRCA = new RecipeCursorAdapter(getActivity(),mCsr);
    mRecipeeList.setAdapter(mRCA);
```

Note! The following (very basic) layouts were used:-

**list_view.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_weight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_supplier_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_supplier_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

recipe_activity.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_servings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingrediant_name_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**The result *(only partial screen shown)* is now :-**

[image]

*Apologies for the colours, not the best.*

Comment: Yes, it is true I'm passing the same cursor between both fragments,
        mCursorAdapter = new PlatformCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
I need to set the cursor here, rather than passing it as null but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Comment: Why don't you get the respective Cursor in the fragment rather than try to pass it?

Comment: how I can do that?

Comment: The same way you get the cursor anywhere you need an instance of the DatabaseHelper (class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper), for which you'll need the context and then call the appropriate method (assuming the method is in the DatbaseHelper). Can't be specific as it would be dependant upon your code. So basically as per the answer, there is a need for other code as the issue is actually outside of the adapters.

Comment: Ok I have done that, created an instance for the DatabaseHelper and got the current cursor. However the problem persists as the same fragment seems to be calling for CursorAdapter although just one is called. Could be that we can't use more than one CursorAdapter?

Comment: You can use multiple CursorAdapters that's not an issue. However I don't believe that you should use the same Cursor for multiple adapters, that could be an issue (not saying you are). What I don't understand is what you mean by this *"CursorAdapter such that each would refer to a certain fragment"*. Adapters don't refer to fragments, rather they are used by Views (e.g ListView). So the adapter should be whever the view is. Do you by anychance mean that the View is not in the fragment that alters the data to be viewed.?

Comment: @Wissam you can use as many `CursorAdapter`s as you wish - all you need is to make sure you are using right `Cursor` - and instead of `getColumnIndex` its better to use `getColumnIndexOrThrow` which saves a lot of time in such cases

Comment: @MikeT yes I mean by that the views, I have used this code to get the current cursor, which worked and each View is having a different cursor,
 DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        currentCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + RecipeEntry.TABLE_NAME_RECIPE, null);
mCursorAdapterRecipe = new RecipeCursorAdapter(getActivity(),currentCursor);
        mCursorAdapterRecipe.changeCursor(currentCursor);
        listView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapterRecipe);
But still the same error persists.

Comment: @pskink I have changed getColumnIndex to getColumnIndexOrThrow but the issue persisted, I still can't figure out why the RecipeCursorAdapter is receiving the wrong cursor.

Comment: @Wissam if you are passing non null `Cursor` to `CursorAdapter` constructor why are you calling `changeCursor` afterwards?

Comment: @pskink I wasn't at first, but because the error persisted I taught this could help, but even removing the changeCursor won't resolve the issue yet.

Comment: @Wissam and if you are not an expert why dont you simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`? just pass layout id, cursor, array of cursor column names and array of view ids- thats all - [here](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) is how to do that

Comment: Ok I will try that @pskink

Comment: @MikeT thanks for this highly elaborated explanation, I shall implement tomorrow morning and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

Ok finally the problem has been resolved, apparently I need to initiate a DatabaseHelper inside each CursorAdapter.

```
public class RecipeCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = RecipeCursorAdapter.class.getName();

public RecipeCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor1){
    super(context, cursor1, 0);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor1, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipe_activity, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor1) {

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + RecipeEntry.TABLE_NAME_RECIPE, null);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Number of Columns " + cursor1.getColumnCount());
    //find which fields would be populated
    TextView recipeName = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
    TextView recipeType = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_type);
    TextView recipeServings = view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_servings);
    TextView recipeValues = view.findViewById(R.id.ingrediant_name_1);
    if(cursor1.moveToNext()) {
        //get the data from the table recipes
        String mRecipeName = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME));
        String mRecipeType = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_TYPE));
        String mRecipeServings = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_SERVINGS));
        String mRecipeValues = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RecipeEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_VALUES));

        //get current item Id
        int currenId = cursor1.getInt(cursor1.getColumnIndex(RecipeEntry._ID));
        //create a content Uri for the current Id
        final Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(RecipeEntry.CONTENT_URI, Integer.toString(currenId));

        //populate fields with their respective data
        recipeName.setText(mRecipeName);
        recipeType.setText(mRecipeType);
        recipeServings.setText(mRecipeServings);
        recipeValues.setText(mRecipeValues);

    }
}
}
```

Thank you all for you support and time @MikeT and @pskink

Comment: no no no - this is not how it works: why you ever want to call `cursor1 = db.rawQuery` inside `bindView` if you have `Cursor cursor` parameter - why dont you simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/PwAcTEsp) you have the snippet of code that shows two different list views - each one with its own `SimpleCursorAdapter` - hope its easy to understand as it counts just 50 lines of code (including xml layout file)

Comment: so did you see that code or the whole (excelent) answer provided by MikeT?

Comment: @pskink yes I just noticed MikeT's comment I will implement tomorrow as it's late now and let you know